# If i tried to making changes in wso2 api manager in publisher in distributed environment, it is not getting reflected soon! Any suggestions for this?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm working on wso2 API manager 2.6.0, if I'm connected to a distributed environment and tried making changes from publisher its not getting reflected soon in store! Any suggestions for this to make it happen as soon as I published.

Comment: What kind of changes are you referring to?

Comment: modifying type from string to object, changes like this and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling registry cache. Open `registry.xml` and set caches to false.

```
    <currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>                       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

    <remoteInstance url="https://localhost">
        <id>gov</id>
        <cacheId>wso2carbon@jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2SHARED_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</cacheId>
        <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>                  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    </remoteInstance>
```

Please note this change in not recommended for production.

Comment: if cache is set to true, how much would it take to reflect in the API store?